# Getting child components prop in Header react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
class RouterConfig extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
  <HashRouter>
   <div>
          <Route component={Header}/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Total} tabkey={1}/>
            <Route exact={true} path='/news/' component={News} tabkey={2}/>
            <Route exact={true} path='/read/' component={ReadNews} tabkey={3}/>
          </Switch>
   </div>
  </HashRouter>
  </div>
)
 }
}
```

I need to get tabKey prop at header component , so I can change header elements depends  on content

Answer (score 0):

You can use render() inside the Route component to pass props. Here's an example:

```
<Route exact path="/example" render={() => {
    return <Child tabKey={1} />;
}} />
```

Comment: I have to identify which component rendered in Switch block in Header component is there any method to identify that ?

Comment: Sure. Set the Route path for your Header component as path="/", which means it's called in all cases, and in your Header, use props.location.pathname to get which path was called. If props.location.pathname is /news, then the News component was called and so on.